# Unable to recognize JS server

Tags: android, react-native

I was trying to setup react native for android. When I finally try to run the application, with **react-native run-android**, I get a message `JS server not recognized, continuing with build...`. The build is completed successfully and installed on the emulator. But since there is no JS server, I get the red screen that says *Unable to download JS bundle*.

Answer (score 4):

This message means you have another service listening on port `8081`, so the JS packager can't be started. You can find what process is blocking the port by running:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN
```

You can stop/kill this process and then run `react-native run-android` again.

Comment: There is no process listening on 8081. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @JophinJoseph did you run the `lsof` command? Are you getting the exact same error (`JS server not recognized`)?

Comment: I ran lsof. It returned no results. When I start to run the app with `react-native run-android`, I get the warning `[warn] JS server not recognized, continuing with build...`. The build is successful, but in the emulator, I get a red screen that says `Unable to download JS bundle`

Comment: It gives 403 Forbidden

Comment: It looks like you have *something* running on that port then, that is not the packager. What OS are you on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90977/discussion-between-felix-and-jophin-joseph).

Comment: How to run this command(lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN) on window machine .....?