# error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to create a react-native project on Android 4.4.2 I get this error screen

[image: said error]

and couldn't find any way to resolve it. I tried restarting packager, reconnecting device, even reinstalling react native and starting new project. On 6.0.0 and later versions it works just fine.

Comment: Did you get this error after executing `react-native run-android`? I'm getting the error in this case which is weird because in debug mode there should be no need for the JS bundle afaik since it's supposed to be connecting to the package server.

Comment: I posted an answer to the same problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110063/706798

Comment: I'm getting this same error message, but for iOS. Anyone have advice? I tried running 'react-native run-ios', but it does not work, because XCode is on an external drive for me.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

A possible solution for this is that you most probably not bundling your application first, perform the following steps and then deploy your app-debug.apk to your device

```
$ cd myproject  
$ react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &  
$ curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

(if the folder `assets` does not exists create it)

Then run from project root

```
$> (cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug)
```

install the created apk to you device, from location: `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

let me know if that fixes your issue

**EDIT**:

You can simply put it to your package.json as a script to automate it, I believe it will be fixed in upcoming releases of react-native and will be executed prior assembling the final APK, hence this won't be needed (I hope as well)

put :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "(cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug)",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "bundle-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --sourcemap-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.map --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"
  },
```

or as mentioned the curl equivalent, but for most cases the above is more robust

Comment: Yes it works!!! What did I just do? why curl? also, can this be automated?

Comment: Thank you very much, Because My app din't link the React native bundle.

Comment: This seems like a hack. If you are packaging the JavaScript into a single file won't you not get the live reloading capability while running the app during development?

Comment: this is not for development but for actual APK packaging

Comment: nothing happen with me still getting error:-
com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Comment: Any suggestion for Windows user ?

Comment: @tbo Please if you're online, respond ASAP. I added the latter in the package.json file and it worked initially. But when I uninstalled to re-install the app, I am getting the same "Could not get BatcheBridge" error. Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: @gbade_  have you been using rnpm instead of npm anywhere in your react native code? I think you would have used it at some point so probable now you used npm install and the links have not been created. This is just a guess, hope it helps

Comment: @tbo I am using npm. I am also running tests on an Android 4.1.2 device. I can't use the development server as that shows red and throws errors of its own. I found a way of fixing the issue. I shook the device, went to Dev Settings, found the IP and port by using ifconfig in terminal and added it to the IP and Port part in the Dev Settings.

Comment: @tbo my application boots now, but I'm not seeing any of the assets.

Answer (score 124):

I came across this issue as well. 
What I did was force kill the app on my device, then I opened up another console and ran

```
react-native start
```

and then I opened the app again from my device and it started working again.

EDIT: If you are using an android device via USB and have unplugged it or your computer went to sleep, you may have to first run

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: This solved my problem when using `react-native run-android`. Using `react-native start` was never required for me when I was doing `react-native run-ios`

Comment: This worked, but why is this happening? Is this going to be fixed? Do I have to always open 2 terminals, and do the 'start' first before I can run it on a device?

Comment: it works for me too ! spent hours to find a solution

Comment: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` was sufficient in itself for me. Many thanks!

Comment: This is awesome after that you could do ./adb install

Answer (score 29):

Just got this error. Here's what I did to fix:
I selected `Dismiss`, Went into the Developer menu, then `Dev Settings`,
Choose `Debug server host & port for device`, I added my computers IP address and the port: `192.168.0.xx:8xxx`, use whatever your developer machines assigned IP address is on your wifi network. The port is usually `:8081`

Once I did this, all went well. Also, while you're in the dev menu remember to select `Enable Live Reload` and `Debug JS Remotely`, it makes your life much-much easier while debugging.

Comment: Works! For ubuntu user: run `ifconfig`, then find inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx where xxx* is your developer machine ip

Comment: This worked for me on an API level 19 / Kitkat 4.4, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525431/getting-error-closed-twice-on-adb-reverse, http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-dev-server-via-wi-fi

Comment: Thank you! I only have to do this config when I debug without USB cable (with tools like WiFi ADB).

Comment: It's important to note that you can make the Developer menu that @cube references above by physically shaking your android device. That may seem odd, but that's what will bring it up. Then follow the rest of the instructions. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 24):

This is what worked for me (After trying every other solution i found ...):

Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` inside `\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: can run this command anywhere, dont have to b in platform-tools

Comment: I found that `react-native run-android` attempts to run that command and depends on the Windows environment variable `path` to contain the `platform-tools` path.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. PATH is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: nope, not working on Windows 10 and Android emulator

Answer (score 16):

I got this also when I started for the first time with React Native, using a physical device. If that's the case, you need to do some extra things before you can get started. You have to enter some information about your development machine in the 'Dev Settings' of React Native.

When you see the error, *shake your device*. A dialog will popup, the last option will be 'Dev Settings'. Select 'Debug server hot & port for device' and enter your local IP and the used port (usually 8081).

See the last paragraph of https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Comment: This is literally a repeat, verbatim of what I said above (in August)

Comment: I didn't know that I need to shake the device. First, I would post it as a comment, but I don't have enough points to do that. I did upvote your post.

Comment: Simplest and cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If none of the solution work for you try this:

I found that my `<root>/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug` folder was empty and by running `cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug` was not creating those files required, which are later used by javascript thread in our react native apps.

I ran manually the following command which the debug build command should have created ideally.

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev true --reset-cache --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output /<path to dir>/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /<path to dir>/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

After running these commands I found two bundle files in this directory `<root>/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug`

And then a I ran again `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug` my app started working again.

Will debug more and would update what is failing actually.

Comment: Just to clarify what's going on it seems that when integrating a react native into an existing project, the bundle output path is NOT set automatically, so you have to set it yourself. Hence the bundle output path=/path/to/assets
?

Comment: You are the best btw.

Answer (score 7):

see [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9336):

1.react-native start

2.click `Reload(R,R)` on your device.

Answer (score 7):

In a **separate** terminal, connect your device to the computer and run the following commands:

```
react-native start 
cd user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
./adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

**Application** terminal:

```
react-native run-android 
install apk on your device from this location android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to include a bit more detail on what the individual steps in your answer mean, from what directories the commands should be run etc? I think that would make your answer much more helpful.

Comment: This the proper answer. This allows you to iterate quickly by connecting to the react native server instead of having to repackage the bundle with each change.

Answer (score 7):

It's little too late but this really works for me.

1. `react-native run-android`.
2. `react-native start`.

First command will build `apk` for android and deploy it on your device if its connected. When you open the App it will show red screen with error. Then run second command which will run packager and build app bundle for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command in terminal and then reload. It worked for me

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Answer (score 5):

1. restart the genymotion
2. run `react-native run-android`
3. the problem was solved

Comment: For real? `restart the genymotion`? Ty vole.

Comment: That is like saying "oh your website does not work? Try restarting your server."

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same exception on the device Z3 Compact D5803 - 6.0.1

I went opened the .buckconfig file and changed the line:

`target = Google Inc.:Google APIs:23`

to

`target = Google Inc.:Google APIs:24`

Because i saw in SDK Manager that Android 6.X has api level 24.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it's because `adb` was not in the `PATH`. It's located  `/Users/man/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` for me, it may be somewhere else for you, but anyway, find it and add it to your path to see if that help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Android < 5.0 you can't use the default `adb reverse` method, but Facebook has added [official documentation to connect to the development server via Wi-Fi](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), which would support your version. Quoting the instructions for MacOS, but they also have them for Linux and Windows:

> **Method 2: Connect via Wi-Fi**
>
> You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP address before proceeding.
>
> You can find the IP address in System Preferences → Network.
>
> Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
> Open your React Native app on your device.
> You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
> Open the in-app Developer menu.
> Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
> Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
> Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Answer (score 3):

It had this issue "randomly" and took me sometime to realize what was wrong in my scenario.

After I have updated to React-native-cli 2.0.1, there was a message output to the log which helped me to dig and find the root cause:

> JS server not recognized, continuing with build...

After researching some links I found this one:

[Unable to recognize JS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604522/unable-to-recognize-js-server)

Since I´m on windows, I ran netstat and found out that my VLC player was also running on port 8081 causing the issue. 
So, in my case, if I started the vlc server prior to the react-native server it wouldn´t work.

This same log message wasn´t output on previous versions of the react-native-cli, making it fail silently.

**TL, DR: check if there´s anything running on the same port as the package manager (8081 by default)**

Answer (score 3):

someone suggested the following one

react-native run-android
react-native start --reset-cache,

But in my case, I just close the cli command prompt window and used the following.

```
npx react-native run-android
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

My way are:

```
react-native start
```

After that in your device using:

```
click to Reload.
```

See in console react-native, it will be fetch js bundle data.

Comment: This was my issue, because the terminal wasn't starting. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I went through my `AndroidManifest.xml` file and had removed the line

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

because my app will not need internet. However, the react native debugging app does need internet access (to access the packager) Whoops. :)

Comment: Man you saved my day. Was ripping my hair off :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. When I did create a react native project via *create-react-native-app AwesomeProject* it worked well in Expo app on phone. After that I wanted to use that quickstart project for developing my project and got same error as you do.

After some research I find out it's better to start new project with *react-native init AwesomeProject* (with all setting in react native docs) Then run this command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

That should fix the thing with bundle (--dev false is not showing warnings)

All you need to do for app to run on your virtual / real device is:

```
react-native run-android
```

And it should be working just fine. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean cache

> react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have following error when you run `react-native run-android`:

`adb server version (XX) doesn't match this client (XX); killing...`

In that case make sure `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb` and `/usr/local/bin/adb` are pointed to the same `adb`

In my case one was pointed to `/Users/sd/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb` (Android SDK), but another was pointed to `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/26.0.2/platform-tools/adb` (Homebrew)

And issue have been fixed after both of them pointed to `/Users/sd/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb` (Android SDK)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too, really confused. cuz all answers does not work.
Just after add **adb** to path.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had side-sync enabled and active. Closing it imediately made the issue go away. It might be worth closing this or any other communication between PC and device

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to open up the port that I was using (8081 by default). On Linux, you can do the following

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8081 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8081 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You can test to see whether you actually need to do this. Just navigate to your dev server in Chrome on your Android device. If it doesn't respond, then this might be what you need. If it does respond, then this won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of us face this problem for the first time, when we start react native project#1.

Few simple steps solved my problem:

I created a sample project using command:

```
react-native init ReactProject1
```

**Solution**

The fix is to help `local-cli\runAndroid\adb.js` to find `adb.exe`, the same way as `local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js`:

find replace statement under projectname(whatever you have given)`\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid`

**Replace:**

```
const devicesResult = child_process.execSync('adb devices');
```

**By:**

```
const devicesResult = child_process.execSync( (process.env.ANDROID_HOME ? process.env.ANDROID_HOME + '/platform-tools/' : '') + 'adb devices');
```

after doing above replacement, just run react-native run-android in your cmd, it will bundle apk and at first try to install js bundle locally in your device. (Got Success)

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that 'adb' was not recognised - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777726/4425405%20) answer.

To fix this add C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools to Environment Variables

Answer (score 1):

"npm start"

I just closed the terminal and open a new one. Went to project location by cd command. And then just simply type - "npm start". and then 'r' for reload. Everything just vanished. I think everybody should try this at once.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the suggestions above/below, but ultimately, the issue I faced was a permissions one with watchman, which was installed using homebrew earlier. If you look at your terminal messages while trying to use the emulator, and encounter 'Permission denied' errors with regards to watchman along with this 'Could not get BatchedBridge" message on your emulator, do the following:

Go to your `/Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents` directory and change the permissions settings so your user can Read and Write. This is regardless of whether or not you actually have a `com.github.facebook.watchman.plist` file in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to also add in a

> react-native upgrade

to get the application to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but it was a stupid mistake from myself...

From **Android studio**, I was launching `installDebug/installRelease` gradle script from `app` projet instead of `root` projet.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest Way!**

- Stop server and end project build.
- Open a 'Node.js' terminal.

  - Navigate to folder with 'react-native' project.
  - Type 'react-native start' --Starting the react native server manually.
- Go to your Code Editor Terminal and type 'react-native run-android.

**You're good to go!**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `jsEngine: 'hermes'` under the android subsection, removing it fixed the production build.

Comment: I had same issue and this helps me. Remeber this fix is for expo go apps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo and you are running it on a physical device, I would advise to kill the metro bundler then expo start and try it

Answer (score 0):

For me i just kill all the terminal inside visual code studio
and open cmd where i run bellow two command

```
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android
```

this is worked for me hope also work for you
happy coding

Answer (score 0):

your app is running already, then stop and again run % npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

I simply interrupted my running application, run `npm i` and then started application again by `npm start` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, go to Privacy > Local Network to see a list of every app that requested access.
I solved by allowing my app to access to the local network.
(Trying to run on physical iPhone device from my mac m1 on the same wifi).

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211870)

Answer (score 0):

terminating the metro bundler and installing the app again works for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and exit the terminal and re run the application helps me!