# Could not get BatchBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Tags: android, debugging, reactjs, react-native, adb

I am trying to run a react-native app I have created. I am getting the below screen when I run it initially in my phone.

[image]

I tried running the "react-native start" and when I run it I get the below output.

[image]

While it stops at "Initializing package manager" I ran the "react-native run-android" in another terminal. Still I get the same BatchBridge error. When I click on the refresh button on the error screen I get the below screen.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? In my code, I only have a console.log. Just a new project to get started. Any advice would be much appreciated. I tried referring to the answer of [error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly) but its a Linux set of commands.

Comment: are your phone and computer on same network?

Comment: no, but why should it be on this case? I'm just running a program that logs "Hello world", with no network connectivities

Comment: This is the error when i forget to set dev settings on my phone (mac os) when both phone and computer on same network and size of project does not matter.

Answer (score 10):

If you are running Android 5.0+, please run the following in a command prompt to connect to the development server:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then, select 'Reload JS' from the Developer menu by shaking the device.

If the above steps are not working or you are running a lower version of Android, please try the following to connect via Wi-Fi:

1. Access the Developer menu, go to the 'Dev Settings'.
2. Select 'Debug server host for device'.
3. Type in your machine IP address and port e.g. 10.0.0.1:8081
4. Try reload the app again by selecting 'Reload JS' from the Developer menu.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo You are right, link only answer might not be the good way to provide an answer which would benefit in a longer term. I have edited my answer to be more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Shake your phone to get "Dev Settings" > Debug server host & port for device > "your IP Address:8081" eg. 192.XXX.XX.xx:8081"

It solved my issue. 
:)

Comment: What is meant by Shake your phone ?

Comment: just shake your phone left-right after you enter into the app

Answer (score 1):

Kill the app on your device, then open up terminal and run the below command

```
react-native start
```

Then open the app again from your device and it will start working.

If you are using an Android device via USB and have unplugged it, you may have to first run

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you are using corrupted jsbundle file. Recreate the jsbundle using

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output music.jsbundle
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have download index.android.bundle file in your asset folder.

Open your project directory and shift key+ right click, open command prompt.
Then paste this command :

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```