# :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error when running react-native run-android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Newbie React Native question here:

When running react-native run-android in the root directory of my test application, I receive the error "Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac".  The test application is a blank app with react-native-maps installed and attempting to use the example files provided in https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/tree/master/example

What I've tried so far:

- Double checked that JAVA_HOME environment variable is set (it is, and other test applications compile without error)
- Attempted to follow the recommendation to "Run with --stacktrace".  This doesn't seem to work, as "react-native run-android --stacktrace" simply results in the error message "error: unknown option `--stacktrace'"
- Looked for the location of some sort of error log that might shed light on the situation.  I was unable to find the expected location of such an error log online, and nothing within the project directory stood out to me as the error log for this.
- cd android && gradlew clean
- react-native upgrade

Can someone please point me in the direction of resolving this error?

Comment: Can you please include the entire output of the command?

Comment: props to @tbo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly