# Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly happened on Android v4.4.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I compiled react-native on Android v4.4.2 but the problems arised:

[image]

I tried to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly), but I did not how to run on Command Prompt Windows 10:

```
$> cd myproject  
$> react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &  
$> curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o
> "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

$> (cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug)
```

I tried to compile the same way on Android V6.0. Then there was no problem at all.

> How to make android V4.4.2 also can be use like Android v6.0 for my first react-native 
>   project development?

Comment: I tried same on Windows 10, but android emulator is still showing the error, tried many other things, too, no fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means your React Native app can't fetch your JS files from your localhost. You'd usually just run `react-native start` to serve the JS files from your packager, but Android 4.4.x cannot connect to your localhost with the default `adb reverse` method.

The way I run on Android 4.4.x is to manually set the device to connect to my machine via Wi-Fi ([Official guide here!](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi)).

1. Access the React Native dev menu by shaking your device or pressing the hardware menu button (can be done with Ctrl+M or Cmd+M in a simulator, IIRC)
2. Go to Dev Settings
3. Under the Debugging section, tap "Debug server host & port for device"
4. Enter your machine's IP address, as well as the port through which the React Native packager is serving, e.g. "10.0.0.25:8081" (make sure your device and your machine are on the same network!)
5. Reload through the dev menu again (or by pressing Ctrl+R or Cmd+R in a simulator, I think)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to try first.

Comment: what about android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: What actually was happened?

Comment: `adb reverse` only works for Android 5.0 and above; OP asks for Android 4.4.2. EDIT: Also just as an FYI, the way I understand it, `adb reverse` binds your Android device's ports to your own machine's ports, so accessing port 8081 would link your device to your package manager running on port 8081 on your localhost.