# How can one connect to an Android TV emulator (on Mac OS) with React Native?

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, react-native, android-tv

I've been messing around with `React Native` today. I've been running my react components on a virtual Android tablet using the `Android Emulator`. I'm now trying to run my react native code on an Android TV emulator, but I can't get it to work. I've set up the TV & Tablet emulators in near identical ways using the `Android Virtual Device Manager` within `Android Studio`. The main difference (beyond the obvious) as far as I can tell is that the CPU for the Tablet is `x86_64`, whereas the CPU for the TV is `x86`. I do not have the option to match these parameters for these two devices.

When I run `react-native run-android`, my react project builds successfully, but then the following screen shows up in my TV emulator. 
[image: Error in Android TV Emulator]
Does anybody know what this is? Is there a proper way to connect a `React Native` app to an android TV emulator? My assumption was that it should be identical to the process for an android tablet emulator, but this does not seem to be the case - and I can't seem to find `android TV` specific information anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that this issue is fixed by the steps recommended by this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39562409/798491 (except instead of shaking your screen, hit `command-m` to bring up the `react native` dev options).

Answer (score 0):

Right now RN doesn't support android TV, they just recently supported apple TV but before that it was supported on ipad. So there must be some additional configurations needed between a tablet and tv. Here is more info on the subject: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10544

Comment: It seems that it is actually possible. It turned out to be an issue that was solved by this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39562409/798491 My `react native` app is now working without issue on my Android TV emulator.

Comment: oh nice, so it was a general android issue. it's cool that android tv works.