# Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

i am having problem with react-native in Android 
(Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly )
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i tried everything : update npm , react-native ,react and all dependencies in package.json to last versions , 
i removed node_modules and reinstall it again , clear cache ... atc

error log

```
 04-25 03:35:49.874 11688-11814/com.test.store E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                                            Process: com.test.store, PID: 11688
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:161)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:465)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$400(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:51)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:481)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:33)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                             Caused by: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                             Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Did you set up the ip server in DevSettings tab in your device?

Comment: yes my local ip 192.168.0.3:8081 and i tried 8088 same thing

Comment: did you uninstall the app and ran react-native run-android again already?

Comment: this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761390/android-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly/62563147#62563147

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue then i followed this answer([error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly/38874952#38874952)) and bang it works like a charm..!

Cheers :)

Comment: it just keep it waiting in blank page ... when i close the app and open it again ... same problem comes up

Comment: delete the application from the device and reinstall it , basically do everything from scratch ...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug with the `react-native-router-flux` package. It is including a duplicate instance of react-native. All you need to do is `npm install` your packages, then remove the duplicate react-native entry.

```
rm -r ./node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that 'adb' was not recognised. When I tried to run my project, there was no obvious indication that there was a problem with 'adb', but when I tried to run blank project it showed that command 'adb' is not recognised.

To fix this add C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools to Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following.

Running `npm start` which gave me an error `ENOSPC`. 
I fixed that error with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600959/706798.

Then I ran `react-native run-android` again, and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Clear your windows temp data. (**Win+R**) Enter **temp** and **%temp%** files. after that **npm start** or **npx react-native start**  (for Metro start) and **npx react-native run-android** (for run the app in the device). that's works for me.
happy coding. :)