# Android "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly"

Tags: android, react-native

I am running the codes here http://rationalappdev.com/react-native-list-app-complete-how-to-guide/, but got the error `Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly"`.

I searched and tried lots of methods, but still got the error. 
e.g.
In on terminal, run `react-native start --reset-cache`
In the other terminal, run `react-native run-android`

My android is `ASUS_X008DC - 7.0`.

Thanks

Comment: try with `react-native start` command and than refresh your application

Comment: Have you tried `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`?

Answer (score 0):

Update dependencies in package.json. It worked for me.

in dependencies:

```
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.2"
```

in devDependencies:

```
"babel-jest": "22.1.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"jest": "22.1.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with   "react": "16.11.0", "react-native": "0.62.2", I deleted my build folder located in project/android/build and did `npm start` with `react-native run android` and it worked