# Issue with Android APK

Tags: android, apk, release, react-native

My app works perfectly when I install it using a usb cable. When I download using HockeyApp or Google Drive it installs, but when I click the app icon it says 'App has stopped'. It will not open the application.

I am using React-Native and Android Studio to build the apk. I generate a signed release and check both signature (v1, v2) boxes.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

****Edit Fixed****

Thank you for all the suggestions.

I have no idea what changed but I started getting a different error so was troubleshooting the new one and everything started working.

Answer of the following post worked:
[error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly)

Comment: will you post logcat?

Comment: You can add crashlytics to the app to check why the app is crashing.. it can provide you the crash logs

Answer (score 1):

For installing an app from any unknown source, you must check it is released app as you define that app is released version then there may be any duplicity in the manifest file.
If you want to check what is the error you must run app from Android Studio and change build variant to relase and for debug app in relase mode

```
release {
            debuggable true
        }
```

it will show what error is comming when you start app in Android Monitor

Comment: I managed to fix it, but thank you for suggesting Android Monitor. I am new to android debugging

Answer (score 0):

I'm found similar apk install issue 1month ago

Crash on app(app is New project)

but I’m found resolve way for this problem
The way is add jackOptions, gradle

```
jackOptions {
     enabled true
    }
```

..I have no idea, Why this problem is resolved..
But resolved this problem

good luck

Comment: jack is deprecated.