# React Native Release APK Crash on startup (Debug works fine)

Tags: react-native

My Android react native is working fine for debug builds, but after building the signed release apk with: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease then it always crashes on startup. The file size of the APK looks pretty similar to the debug one (not a huge difference). Here is the error from logcat.
(I have checked the other stackoverflow issues on release ask problems but could not find a solution. I have also tried 'gradle clean' build).

React-native version 0.44

```
01-17 14:08:13.694 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208)
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                     Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
01-17 14:08:13.922 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                 Process: com.challengesolutions.lifeapp, PID: 9250
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208)
                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                  Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the problem is in the `AppRegistry`. Please check your code again. and link your AppRegistry properly.

Comment: Hey @SathishSundharam - thanks for the comment. So the AppRegistry runs perfectly fine in debug using:
AppRegistry.registerComponent('lifepoints', () => MainApp);
and then:
class MainApp extends React.Component

Any other ideas how I can check the AppRegistry crash for release?

Comment: Hi @Dave - this link may help you..have a look at this [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly).

Comment: Hi @SathishSundharam I have been gone through with the given link but it is for debug version not for the release version. I am facing same issue with the release version. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @DaveHurst, did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem here