# error “Error calling AppRegistery.runApplication” on start of app

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

Trying to run the react-native android application. Getting following error attached below:

[image]

and couldn't find any way to resolve it. I tried restarting packager, reconnecting device, restarting the emulator as well run the command `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and found the solution at 
[error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly)

Chech it once.