# How can resolve problem "BatchedBridge" in react-native?

Tags: react-native

[image: I do not get solution for this problem, will you help me please?]

I had a problem with Sdk and after finding the solution I encountered this problem. I don't know if I deleted a file without realizing it.

This is my App.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MoviesAndMe",
    "slug": "MoviesAndMe",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

And my App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
//import Search from './Components/Search.js'

export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return (
        //<Search />
        <Navigation/>
      );
  }
}
```

I had a problem with Sdk and after finding the solution I encountered this problem. I don't know if I deleted a file without realizing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly" on start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870710/error-could-not-get-batchedbridge-make-sure-your-bundle-is-packaged-properly)