# JS server not recognized, continuing with build

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, react-native

**Environment**

Windows 10

Npm 5.5.1

react-native-cli 2.0.1

react-native 0.50.3

Genymotion Google Nexus 7 - 6.0.0 API 23

**Android stuff:**

Sdk Version: 26

buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

TargetsdkVersion: 26

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"

I have run npm start --reset-cache as well as react-native start --reset-cache but I keep getting the JS server not recognized, continuing with build. This prevents the packager bundling the assets before running on my Emulator.

I have followed solution 1 on this post:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9136#issuecomment-306486102

as well as this one:

[Unable to recognize JS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604522/unable-to-recognize-js-server)

I started this project with react-native init APP. Already having trouble building it with this error. checking serval posts on here and other sites mentioned using npm cache clean and react-native start --reset-cache and that did not seem to help I keep getting the same error. I had it running smoothly at one time but I altered an npm package and I think I broke it again. any help would be appreciated. I also updated the gradle version and synced that into the project

Heres some screenshots of what I am experiencing...

[image: Emulator Output]
[image: Bash Output]

** CODE **

**index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('hihi', () => App);
```

**App.js**
    /**
     * Sample React Native App
     * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
     * @flow
     */

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "name": "hihi",
  "displayName": "hihi"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "hihi",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0",
        "react-native": "0.50.3",
        "watchman": "^0.1.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "jest": "21.2.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE UPDATE**

I figured it out, it was a combination of the suggestions on this post and this solution as well:

[Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

I needed to include google() in **both** locations as well as the solution of switching it to port 8082 and enabling that port on the emulator. THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!! =)

Comment: Asumming you are running this from a local emulator, can you post some code? Specially the stuff that you changed.

Comment: Honestly, I get this even when I react-init an app so I can even show you that. I'm taking screen grabs now

Comment: Please add your App code and the code please, not pictures. I can barely see them lol

Comment: Is there anything else that I'm missing from the code that you would like to see

Comment: Very weird, although you are using a very new version of RN, and they usually break stuff with eery release. I don't update the core version unless I really need to. I actually don't see any issue in your code or screenshots. When running in debug, the JS manager does not bundle right away, it is waiting for the first request from the emulator/device. Are you installing the APK? After starting the APK do you see the js manager console saying it is bundling? I don't fully understand why you said you messed with the npm package but this is the sample project.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to delete the node_modules folder and install everything again.

Comment: I went through a series of steps to get a starter project up and running and then it stopped working again. I'm still working on a solution and I will post it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 20):

Steps that helped me in similar case:

1. Running packager on port different than 8081: `react-native start --port 8082 --reset-cache`
2. Running command `react-native run-android --port 8082` in second Command Prompt window.
3. After error screen appear clicking `Ctrl + M`.
4. Clicking `Dev Settings` button at the bottom.
5. Clicking `Debug server host & port for device` button.
6. Writing `localhost:8082` and clicking `OK` button.
7. Again running command `react-native run-android --port 8082`

Comment: Cool.. I did that and at least connected to my server, but I was met with this error again:



`Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling index.js  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/1), failed.
error: bundling failed: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots: ["c:\'starter_application_name"]
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (MY_COMPUTER\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:305:11)
    at DependencyGraph.getDependencies`

Comment: its looking for index.js and not finding it for some reason =/

Comment: First idea. Could you try command `react-native start --port 8082 --reset-cache `?

Comment: And in points 2. and 7. it will be command: `react-native run-android --port 8082`

Comment: could it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Git-Bash instead of cmd prompt?


I can access android in cmd by using "android" but that doesn't show up in my git bash, I've added my PATH variables and everything, I'm trying to add them to my bashrc file as well.


This wasn't something that was causing problems before so I'm trying every available avenue I can think of. Thank you all for your effort! =)

Comment: I'm going to follow this post because I think this is the problem I'm experiencing:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows

Comment: It really helped me. Can anyone explain why the normal thing is not working?

Comment: @Navin prasad, because the default port 8081 is most likely occupied by another process.

Comment: I am stuck at "warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
" What should  be done next.?

Comment: Where should I write => ctrl+M

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I had another process running on port `8081`.

1. Find the process `lsof -i tcp:8081`
2. Get the PID, in my case `25120`
3. Kill the process: `kill -9 25120`
4. Start React Native Again

Answer (score 1):

Just changing port doesnt solve the issue, instead it creates more unless you also change the port from the device itself.

First, confirm if its the case:

```
$> netstat -aon|findstr “8081”
```

Now change it to run from a new Default Port

a) Change env variable on windows to set a new port for RN:

```
$> SET RCT_METRO_PORT=8083
```

This is used in RN to use as the default port, and if not set it defaults to 8081

b) Remove old reverse:

```
$> adb reverse –remove-all
```

c) Set new reverse port for the adb device:

```
$> adb reverse tcp:8083 tcp:8083
```

d) Change Dev Settings on the device from the default 8081 to 8083.

Run the app and then run input keyevent 82, 
now select **Dev Settings > Debug Server host … > enter new url:
localhost:8083**

build and run again

Answer (score 0):

In my case (had the same error) I simply checked netstat in win CMD ([check for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)). My problem was running another instance on port :8081 so I had to kill the bastard.

1. Close all running local server instances.
2. Check link for reference on killing :8081 proccess on Windows
3. Rebuild & rerun project.
4. Profit

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off a local server program like MAMP, WAMP, OpenServer e.t.c. They can use the 8081 port.