# unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to create the native react app by learning some tutorials and using react-native-cli. I am getting this error while running the application on android platform using `react-native run-android`script.
The error I am getting is `unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle. Make sure your build is packaged correctly and you are running a packager server`. 
I tried setting port for TCP. After reading a lot of articles here I found this solution by running the command

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android`

So I added this command in my package.json. Now every time I have to run this command for the changes in code, live refreshing is not working and as I have seen in many tutorial that a development server will start but nothing is starting.

[image][image]

I still didn't understand why this error occurs and why not a JS development server is starting ?

Here is the info of react version -
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

Comment: But my development server is not working and I can't resist myself to re run this script on every changes.If anyone found any solution and explain why the development server is not opening when running the command to live watch the changes.

Comment: also duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341120/js-server-not-recognized-continuing-with-build (`:8081` might be in use).

Comment: try command in project root directory `react-native start` and then run